# focusout() and trigger.('focusout') not causing input to lose focus

Tags: javascript, jquery, focus

I'm using the jQuery UI modal dialog, and populating it with some form fields.  Because of this bug: http://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/4731, the first input gains focus when the dialog opens.  To get around that, I'm trying to blur the affected input when the dialog is opened.

The problem is that there exists other functionality which is called for this input on a `.blur()`, and I *don't* want to fire that functionality for this.

So, I'm trying to use `.focusout()`and `.trigger('focusout')` to achieve the same effect, but with no results.

Doing either of these:

```
$('#input-id').focusout();
$('#input-id').trigger('focusout');
```

does not actually cause the input to lose focus, where using `.blur()` is successful.  Am I missing something, or is there another way to accomplish what I need?

Comment: Why would you not use $('#input-id').trigger('blur') in your case ? Because it works and would probably be the easiest way do do this..

Comment: $('#input-id').trigger('blur'); is a working solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My suggestion would be to set the focus to some other element in the dialog when it is opened instead of setting textbox to blur. This should overcome your problem.

Hope this Helps!!

Comment: What if there is only one element?

Comment: I think he wants you to add an hidden element somewhere a trigger a blur on this hidden element to force the focusOut on the selected element

Answer (score 24):

If you fancy a quick javascript hack you could use:

`$(':focus').blur();`

Comment: The `:focus` selector finds the element that is currently focused and then blur takes the focus off the element, thus calling the `focusout` function

Answer (score 4):

Focusout does not cause the element to lose focus. Instead focusout is triggered when an element loses focus. Check out http://api.jquery.com/focusout/

Answer (score 3):

I used this as a workaround:

```
$('body').focus();
```

Comment: Wouldn't work if it's triggered by clicking on another element, which is usually the case. Basically every time you'd navigate away from the element in question, the body would steal focus.

Answer (score 0):

I used this without needing to execute javascript in the selenium driver:

```
field.send_keys :tab
```